# Android Studio: add project as library

Tags: java, android, dependencies, android-studio

I want to add [this](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-typeface-textview) project as library to my project in android studio.
this is what I tried,

I have my project directory as `f:/my project/my app/src`
and my library in `f:/my project/my library/src`

I import the module (the library) by going to `file > import module > selecting the library`
then I got to `file > project structure > modules > dependencies tab > select my project > add module dependency apply ok and then done`

however when I use the code from the library I get the usual syntax error (the class ... could not be found)

also I noticed this popup (see image)

[image]

I am new to android studio or intelliJ, how do I fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are a novice, I recommend to use eclipse and adt. Android studio is not stable yet and you will get many problems with it.

Comment: I have used eclipse for a month now, but I want to try android studio

Comment: I used eclipse, I used IntelliJ idea, it is simple to work with both, but android studio - I had many problems and I decided to wait for stable release.

Comment: I suppose a simple task like adding a project as library is not much of a big deal and android studio should be stable at doing that

Comment: also is the process I mentioned above correct

Comment: Use intellij idea and later move to android studio. Now I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `settings.gradle` file (in directory `f:/my project`), it must contains something like this:

```
include 'my app','my library'
```

If this file don't exists: create it manually. The `settings.gradle` contains the list of gradle modules in a multi-module project.

Then you must add the dependency to your library in app. To do so edit the `my app/build.gradle` and add this line :

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':my library')
}
```

I also notice that you don't use default structure for your projects (i.e. you put the code in `src/` instead of `src/main/java`) so you will have to overwrite some values of the default fileSet in the `build.gradle` of your projects. Be sure to have something like this in `my app/build.gradle` and `my library/build.gradle` :

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```